# Error when casting Nil TJSONValue using 'as' operator

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have stumbeled accross an error that cought me totally by surprise, so I wanted to check with you if this makes sense...

```pascal
Item := Songs.Items[Index] as TJSONObject;
ThisTrack := Item.Values['track'] as TJSONObject;
if (Assigned(ThisTrack)) then Begin;

End;
```

`Songs` is a `TJSONArray`, `Item` and `ThisTrack` are `TJSONObject`.

If `Item` does not contain a "track", the above code throws an `ERangeError` exception on the 2nd line.

This is the first time I'm seeing this, and I am VERY sure, I had "NIL AS <something>" a lot in the past.

Is this a JSON-class specific issue?

Is the workaround for this really as follows?

```
ThisTrack: TJSONValue;

Item := Songs.Items[Index] as TJSONObject;
ThisTrack := Item.Values['track'];
If Assigned(ThisTrack) then Begin;
  Tracks := (ThisTrack as TJSONObject).Values['uri'].Value);
```

Comment: The problem was that the `track` value was there, but had the value null. My previous JSON object returned NULL for the value in that case, now I need to check for `ThisTrack.null`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TJSONObject.Values[]` property returns a `nil` pointer if the requested child is not found.

The `as` operator does not raise an exception if given a `nil` pointer, it will return a `nil` pointer.  So whether you cast or not, you still need to check for `nil` before accessing an object that may or may not exist.

Regarding the `ERangeError` exception, you can't get that error on the `Item.Values['track'] as TJSONObject` expression, as you indicated.  But you could get it from the `Songs.Items[Index]` expression, if `Index` is out of bounds.

Also, you have an erroneous `;` after `Begin`, you need to remove that.